# Elastic Search Query: Do not retrieve a field if condition is true

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I'm trying to implement a generic search which allows searching through all types of documents including an account type document. I need to create an elasticsearch query in such a way that if a document is `type:"account"` then the field named `password` won't get returned. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Although looping through the result will work but it would be best if it elasticsearch can support it.

Comment: Do you have a condition where the `password` field should be returned? If not, you can simply exclude the password field using [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html)

Comment: The actual field is really named `pass`. This has been the convention throughout the system and I would need permission to change it to something else. Renaming it to something like _password and putting it on the source filter as an exemption is the backup option since it's easier. But it would be interesting if elasticsearch can do what we want.

Comment: You didn't answer my question :-)